# android sending and receiving data from Mysql by passing certain parameters

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to do send and receive in android. Where send some parameters to the database and based up on those I would like to receive the data and display in text view but I could not find my problem. Please me in solving this code. I would to do in background.

Here is my code

```
class Question extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(day1q1.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Question. Please wait...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All details from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
        {
            String result = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            StringBuilder sb = null;

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/get_Q.php");
                 nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("day",dayno.toString()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Qno",Q.toString()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }
            // convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                String line = "0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            JSONArray jArray;
            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                qns = new String[jArray.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    qns[i] = json_data.getString("Question");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Question", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

                }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
        {   
            dialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {   
                        System.out.println("usersMap.get(Question) : " + qns[0]);                     
                        Question.setText(qns[0]);   


                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Is there an error? Stacktrace? or does it just not work

Comment: And probably shouldn't use your real ip address in the question

Comment: you need to study how to have a thread or async task update a view in the GUI. Do you have code for that ? If so, please post it.

Comment: Darussian it does not work.